# High level retry logic for activities which failed to be sent

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

For a month my bot started getting timeouts while sanding or receiving the activities on Teams. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/176) on bot framework github.

> I am creating new issue as all the similar ones refer to the begining of conversation or the Direct Line channel and not Teams.
>   I am getting 502 Bad Gateway error randomly and cannot find a root cause.
>   So far it happened 2 times out of about 30 conversation with the bot.
>   Both errors occurred in the middle of conversation in exactly the same waterfall step while bot displays the hero card with buttons to the user.
>
> The first time bot sent the hero card and user clicked the button but then the error occurred. Below is the stack trace and application insights screenshot.
>
> Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException:
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations+d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions+d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter+d__28.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext+<>c__DisplayClass22_0+<g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TelemetryLoggerMiddleware+<>c__DisplayClass7_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext+d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.TextPrompt+d__1.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Prompt`1+<BeginDialogAsync>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+<BeginDialogAsync>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+<PromptAsync>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Assistant.GetTicketDetailsDialog+d__4.MoveNext (Assistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\user\source\repos\Assistant Repository\Assistant\Dialogs\SubDialogs\GetTicketDetailsDialog.csAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 83)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog+d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog+d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog+d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog+d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Assistant.RootDialog+<GetDetailsAsync>d__6.MoveNext (Assistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\user \source\repos\Assistant Repository\Assistant\Dialogs\RootDialog.csAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 92)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog+<OnStepAsync>d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog+<RunStepAsync>d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog+<ResumeDialogAsync>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+<EndDialogAsync>d__25.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Prompt`1+d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog+d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext+d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Assistant.Assistant+d__8.MoveNext (Assistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\user\source\repos\Assistant Repository\Assistant\Assistant.csAssistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 70)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TelemetryLoggerMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter+TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware+d__0.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet+d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter+d__14.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>   image
>
> The second time bot tried sending the same hero card but it failed as the user have not received the card. Below is the stack trace and application insights screenshot.
>
> Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadGateway'
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TelemetryLoggerMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<OnTurnAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ChoicePrompt.OnPromptAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, IDictionary`2 state, PromptOptions options, Boolean isRetry, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Prompt`1.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.PromptAsync(String dialogId, PromptOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Assistant.RootDialog.GetTypeAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\user\source\repos\Assistant Repository\Assistant\Dialogs\RootDialog.cs:line 75
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.OnStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.RunStepAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 index, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Assistant.Assistant.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\user\source\repos\Assistant Repository\Assistant\Assistant.cs:line 101
>   image

After their investigation I have received the response that it is a 'transient' issue and 'request to underlying dependency had timed out' so I should implement some retries. As it getting more and more frequent I started to think about the solution.

So the question is how to implement high level retries on activities which have failed to reach the user/bot. Should I put the begindialogasync in try-catch block and put the dialogcontext.RepromptDialogAsync() in catch?

Or it would be better to deep dive and find the root cause?

Comment: The only time I've gotten this error is when running NGrok, and I've forgotten to actually "run" the project in Visual Studio. I have multiple bots hosted on Azure, and have never seen this on a live bot. Where is your bot hosted?

Comment: On Azure. It has been running without any issue for over 3 month

Comment: just standard Web App hosted? What pricing plan is it on?

Comment: It's standard App Service, D1: shared.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell -for sure-, but it's possible that's the problem. D1, although it has more minutes that F1, is still limited to a certain amount of minutes per day (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/). Is it possible you'd hit those limits? Are you able to upgrade to, say B1, and test for a little while?

Comment: We are currently in the midst of rolling out a new version of our back-end service that powers all Teams chats, and we are seeing increased 502 volume. We are working to fix it - assuming this isn't an issue with Azure D1 capacity, it should go away soon. That said, putting the code in try/catch blocks seems like a good defensive measure - it really should be intermittent but it can happen occasionally.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thank you, as per the app service metrics sum of minutes for last 30 days was 43 minutes so I don't think we are hitting 240 minutes/day. In case of plan upgrade we don't have a budget for that.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Thank you. Is there any expected date of the roll-out completion?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the issue Bill raised, but that certainly seems the most likely culprit, given his information!